# how to comment a story line in JBehave Story

Tags: jbehave

I have a story line as follows

```
Scenario: 

Given user is on Login page

When user types login details with xxx as user xxx as passwd and submits

Then dashboard is shown
```

please advise, how to comment or not to make run for a line(example: 2 line should not undergo for test after 1 directly 3 line)

Answer (score 39):

You want to temporarily disable a step in your scenario? Comment the line using the prefix `"!-- "`, such as

```
Given user is on Login page
!-- When user types login details with xxx as user xxx as passwd and submits
Then dashboard is shown
```

**The space right after the !-- is mandatory.** Thanks @flaz14

See documentation on JBehave: http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/grammar.html

Comment: Doesn't work anymore. Commented line is merged with previous parseable line.
Does anyone know some trick to comment part of *.story file?

Comment: Though @dexx wrote this on 2013, it still doesn't work. Anything new on this?

Comment: Hello there, @Nom1fan - Do you have examples to reproduce this? (I don't have a recent installation at hand) Because if so, it would be a long unnoticed bug; If you search the source repository at https://github.com/jbehave/jbehave-core for the string "!--" you'll find various examples and the corresponding code to handle it.

Comment: @flaz14: That's not clear from the grammar or the FAQ. :-(

Comment: The space right after the !-- should be omittted. It Must follow with the first letter of the comment.

Answer (score 6):

I know this an old question, but I have found a solution for this, and I share for the community :

'!-- ' is the sign for cancellable step, means steps that need to be disabled.

In our project, we use a story Parser :

```
this.currentConf.useStoryParser(new TransformingStoryParser(this.currentConf.storyParser(), this.transformComment, this.transformCutter));
```

We needed to put documentation in user stories, so we made a difference between comments and cancellable steps :

`!-- Then ...` => Cancellable steps (native way)

`!--| This is a a comment...` => Comment

With the transformer, comments are stripped from the story before it is executed.

This is the same for '|--', a cancellable **example**. We have introduced '|--|', or a 'cutter' to prevent the rest of the story to be executed.

The classes (this.transformComment, this.transformCutter) :

```
    public class ParserTransformingComment implements StoryTransformer {

        public ParserTransformingComment() {
        }


        /**
         * Suppression de commentaires
         */
        private Rewriter vC = new Rewriter("(?ms)^((!--\\|[^\\r\\n]*)(?:\\r?\\n)?)") {
            @Override
            public String replacement() {
                System.out.println("Ignoré : " + this.group(1));            
                return "";
            }
        };

        @Override
        public String transform(String pStoryAsText) {
            return vC.rewrite(pStoryAsText);
        }

    }

    public class ParserTransformingCutter implements StoryTransformer {    
        public ParserTransformingCutter() {
        }

        /**
         * Gestion des 'cutter'.
         */
        private Rewriter vS = new Rewriter("(?ms)^(\\|--\\|.*)") {
            @Override
            public String replacement() {
                System.out.println(">>> Cette section va être ignorée : ");
                System.out.println(StringUtils.lineStart("> ",this.group(1)));
                System.out.println("-------------");            
                return "";
            }
        };


        @Override
        public String transform(String pStoryAsText) {
            return vS.rewrite(pStoryAsText);
        }

    }
```

**EDIT:**
As of Jbehave 4.3, comments are handled in a better way, even without StoryTransformer :

```
!--BlahBlah -- ignored completely by Jbehave
!-- Then ... -- steps ignored (registered in the report)
!-- Blah blah -- comment (registered in the report)
```

Regards,
David C.

Comment: Upvoted, and downvoted the top one. This answer is much more precise and helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Eclipse IDE then you can use shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to comment single / multiple story line.

Answer (score 1):

Use this `!--` When user types login details with xxx as user xxx as password and submits. 
Note :For comment "`!--`" space is mandatory otherwise it will execute the step.